# Find $\int_{0}^{\frac{r}{2}} {\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}^{-1}} \ \text{d}p$

Tags: probability, integration, combinatorics

Now also asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/335627/11260) **and answered affirmatively [there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/335978/123045)**.

---

Let there be $n$ pairs of shoes in a box.
The the probability that from the $r \le n$ shoes I am taking out of the box there are exactly $p$ pairs is given by
\begin{equation*}
        \mathbb{P}_{n}^{(r)}(p)
        = \frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}}.
\end{equation*}
For $n = 15$ and $r \in \{6,8,10\}$. The function (assuming the continuous factorial equivalents) looks like this:
[image]

> I am interested in finding the area under that curve, namely
> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{r}{2}} \frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}} \ \text{d}p$$
> According to numerical estimates in the comments I suspect that it converges to 1 for $n = r \to \infty$.

I consulted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864930/evaluate-int-x-choose-n-dx-problem-798-crux-mathematicorum) but could derive how that would help me.

I also thought about writing the first product of binomial coefficients as $$
\binom{n}{n - p}\binom{n - p}{r - 2p}
$$
which is similar to the form $\binom{f(x)}{f(y)} \binom{f(y)}{f(x)}$ mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602215/int-01-int-01-binom-textsomething-textsomething-binom-textsomethin).

Comment: Seems not: $(1,1): 0.4593\dots$, $(2,2): 0.7220\dots$, $(3,3): 0.8580\dots$, and the integral for $n = r$ appears to monotonically increase for larger $n$.  It's around $1 - 10^{-6}$ for $n = 20$.

Comment: In other words, we want to show that $$\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{4^p\left(n-2p\right)!\left(p!\right)^2}\,dp\sim\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^n\left(n!\right)^3},$$
or using Stirling's approximation,
$$\int_0^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{4^pp^{2p+1}(n-2p)^{n-2p+\frac12}}\,dp\sim\frac{2\sqrt\pi}n\left(\frac{2}n\right)^n.$$